# Button being placed outside site inner

Tags: html

For a reason I cant find the button that is supposed to be centered underneath the two columns is being placed to the side

https://tandarts-haarlem.nl/haarlem-zuid-centrum/

Can anyone tell me what im missing?

```
<p style="text-align: center;">Een tandarts voor uzelf, uw kinderen of ouders;
Onze tandartspraktijk is gelegen op de grens van Haarlem centrum en Haarlem zuid.</p>

<div class="one-half first">
<div class="left-content"><i class="fa fa-compass fa-2x"></i></div>
<div class="right-content"><h3>Vaste tandarts</h3>
In onze praktijk voert steeds dezelfde tandarts de regie over de aan u geboden zorg.</div>
</div>

<div class="one-half">
<div class="left-content"><i class="fa fa-comments-o fa-2x"></i></div>
<div class="right-content"><h3>Wij nemen de tijd om te luisteren</h3>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
</div>

<div class="one-half first">
<div class="left-content"><i class="fa fa-diamond fa-2x"></i></div>
<div class="right-content"><h3>Global Support</h3>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
</div>

<div class="one-half">
<div class="left-content"><i class="fa fa-smile-o fa-2x"></i></div>
<div class="right-content"><h3>Cosmetische tandheelkunde</h3>
Om het u makkelijker te maken ons buiten werktijd te bezoeken zijn wij op donderdagavond tot 21u geopend.</div>
</div>

<div class="one-half first">
<div class="left-content"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up fa-2x"></i></div>
<div class="right-content"><h3>Global Support</h3>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
</div>

<div class="one-half">
<div class="left-content"><i class="fa fa-clock-o fa-2x"></i></div>
<div class="right-content"><h3>Avondopening</h3>
Om het u makkelijker te maken ons buiten werktijd te bezoeken zijn wij op donderdagavond tot 21u geopend.</div>
</div>

<p class="center" style="text-align: center;"><a class="button large" href="https://tandarts-haarlem.nl">Klik hier voor meer informatie</a></p>
```

Comment: show a MVCE instead a link

Comment: add `clear:both` to the containing `p`

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your time guys. 
Im new to this and its showing i guess =)

I've added the code as it was originally. I'll try adding the clear:both and see how that works out

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the solution @Gaba aka G. Petrioli =)

Answer (score 0):

You should try just doing something like

```
#but_1 { position: absolute; right:whateverpx; top:whateverpx; }
```

It seems a little simpler than what your doing

It is in css, just thought I should clarify

Answer (score 0):

Your button is in a paragraph that is following other floated elements and you need to clear them. To the paragraph containing the button, add `clear:both`

Answer (score 0):

Edited the code for the paragraph the button is in to:

```
<p>
<div style=clear:both> 
<a class="button large" href="tandarts-haarlem.nl">Klik hier voor meer informatie</a> 
</div> </p>
```

solved